# positioning buttons on top of a div nd making each of their widths 1/3 the div

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

i want the 3 button to be on top of the div no matter where or how big is the div and making each of their widths 1/3 of the div width. I tried putting it inside the div and give it `position: absolute; top: -x%` but it just disappears.

Comment: Maybe the div has `overflow: hidden` set? Without all the relevant CSS we can only speculate.

Comment: Is wrapping both `div` and `buttons` in a `div.wrapper` an option?

Comment: yes it is an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the buttons are inside the 'div': Try giving overflow: visible to the 'div'. And z-index: 1 to the buttons.

Otherwise if the buttons are outside the 'div' you would need javascript that positions the buttons accordingly using the div's getBoundingClientRect() values.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.wrapper-1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapper-2 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  /* Absolute element */
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 70px;
}

.content {
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 100%;
}

.btns {
  display: flex;
}

.btns button {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!-- Wrapper 1 -->
<div class="wrapper wrapper-1">
  <div class="btns">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    div
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Wrapper 2 -->
<div class="wrapper wrapper-2">
  <div class="btns">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    div
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.content` overflows `.wrapper` by the height of `.btns`. You could make `.wrapper { display: flex; flex-direction: column }` and `.content { flex: 1 }` or you could do `.btns { position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 100% }` risking that the buttons get cut off if there's not enough space above the box.